# How to pass information between views

Tags: iphone, ios4, uinavigationcontroller

I want to pass information like number between two views in navigation controller. But I don't know how.

Thanks

Comment: This question has been asked [many times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010523/how-to-access-one-uiviewcontrollers-properties-from-another-uiviewcontroller) [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943929/how-to-pass-information-from-appdelegate-into-one-of-the-view-controllers-in-the) on StackOverflow. [Have a look around](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option might be using singletons if the "numbers" are just a synonym for your application model. Remember, you should use the MVC-concept!

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html

Try the SynthesizeSingleton.h macro if you want a tough solution!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use delegates and protocols. Here is a site with an example http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html